# How to open Device Manager as admin?

Tags: windows-10, administrator, device-manager

My company has made our Win10 users to be "standard users" (without admin rights). However, there is a possibility to run a program using admin rights with some "auto elevation" (Avecto Defendpoint?) system. What I would normally do is "right click" -> "Run as administrator", but that option is not available with Device Manager. I am able to run Powershell as admin, for example (with Right click -> Run as Administrator).

How would I open the Device Manager with Admin rights?

#### What have I tried and which does not work

- Right clicking "Device Manager" in start menu -> "Run as Administrator" (there is no such option)
- Running with Win+R -> devmgmt.msc. (It starts with standard user rights)

Comment: Try [SuRun](https://sourceforge.net/projects/surun/) and be done with it ;) ... typically when you want to run something as admin you need to prefix the command with `runas`. In case of the device manager you'd start the `devmgmt.msc` MMC snap-in and presumably via `mmc.exe` ... which in turn could be prefixed with `runas`.

Comment: There is not really a need to run Device Manager as Admin. The components inside (to update, change, install) need admin rights.  Why do standard users need Device Manager?  We do not see this at our clients.

Comment: @0xC0000022L Well that's an interesting option, actually. Only thing is that I would want to read the source and compile the software myself before using it, so if there is an option without 3rd party packages, it would be better.

Comment: @John Well there are certain situations I might need run Device Manager as Admin. Currently, I need to test a USB device with two different drivers, and for removing/reinstalling drivers I need admin rights. Maybe the question then is why I am a standard user, lol.

Comment: You need Admin credentials to do the installs you want. No way around that.

Comment: Why can’t you install the drivers normally with your Administrator account?  Starting Device Manager won’t prevent the need for Administrator access.  You will still receive a UAC prompt, even if you find a way, to elevate Device Manager.

Comment: @np8 yep, the code is straightforward, but you need a good grasp of NT security concepts. Oh and it builds pretty much out of the box although I admittedly went ahead and built my own projects with premake4 as well as projects to build via the WDK.

Comment: @Ramhound untrue. Please check out SuRun and you'll see that with a little help from a privileged helper (i.e. a Windows service) you can indeed achieve this. Besides, as Mark Russinovich pointed out UAC is not a security feature and never was meant to be, so no harm in cutting it out of all this.

Comment: I personally was already aware of that program.  I also know elevation of a process doesn’t necessarily prevent a UAC prompt.  It’s also unnecessary, to talk down to me, like I am not knowledgeable about Windows.

Comment: Microsoft has become so ****** to remove the right click option and every pro feature. Each day they make switching to another OS more and more likely. This is pure PITA!

Answer (score 21):

Found a satisfying solution. Just start up Device Manager normally (without admin rights), and then press "Change Settings" -button in the General tab:

[image: device manager general tab]

This will open up the Properties window again but with Admin rights (at least, with the Defendpoint Auto-Elevation).

---

It is also possible to open the Device Manager with admin rights from a Powershell *with admin rights* with

```
start "C:\Windows\System32\devmgmt.msc"
```

Comment: No problem to open Device Manager. The issue comes with driver install and uninstall

Comment: Why the downvote? This works as intended. Got my drivers uninstalled without any problems.

Comment: @np8 - This does not actually launch Device Manager with elevated rights.

Comment: It does. Note that I ran it from Powershell *with admin rights*.  When launching Powershell with admin rights, I get a UAC prompt (or similar).

Answer (score 13):

**Step 1**: Run `Command Prompt` as administrator

**Step 2**: Type `devmgmt.msc` and press Enter

[image]

OR

**Step 1**: C:\Windows\System32

**Step 2**: Right-click devmgmt, Run as administrator

Answer (score 4):

Open <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type `devmgmt.msc`

Now **do not** click OK, but use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>

This will start it as administrator.

Comment: I tried it on my Windows 10 machine and it still worked.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution:

You can start the Computer Management (compmgmt) as administrator the usual way. In there you have a node to open the device manager as pane inside the computer management window.

Answer (score 2):

Old thread, but thought I'd give me two-pennies worth.

1. Right-click an empty space on the desktop
2. New > Shortcut
3. In the Create Shortcut Wizard, type "devmgmt.msc" > click "Next"
4. Name it "Device Manager" > click "Finish"
5. A shortcut will appear on your desktop
6. Right-click the shortcut and select "Run as Administrator"

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Win</kbd> to open the "Start menu", type `devmgmt.msc` into the search box ("Type here to search"), press <kbd>Right arrow</kbd> followed by <kbd>Down arrow</kbd> to highlight "Run as administrator", press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute.

Comment: A little easier might be, after typing `devmgmt.msc`, to simply press `ctrl`+`shift`+`enter` to start it as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

you can open devmgmt.msc from cmd with admin rights 
or you can open task manager>**file** tab > new task > check the "**run with administrative previllages**" option and open devmgmt.msc

Comment: The Task manager -> "New task" does not seem to have an option to run anything with admin rights.

Comment: It's simpler to open an admin command line window and type "devmgt.msc" from there.

Comment: @Didier yes you're right.. that's actually why i put it as the first option

Comment: if you don't see that option in new task then try to just open the device manager as normal user, and when you try to edit something you'll be asked for admin password

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed it! That's usually how we do it when we remote assist users with driver issues and the like.

Answer (score 0):

## Run CMD as Elevated

If your company windows allows you to run some programs as elevated, try this:

1. Type CMD on the windows search
2. Right-click the command prompt and click **Open File Location**
3. On the folder that opens, right click the Command Prompt shorcut and click **Run Elevated**

This isn't admin, but it gives you some rights, such as opening the device manager to try to update some drivers. I haven't fully explored the possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You can also launch MMC  as admin, then add device manager to MMC as a snap-in.  Additionally you can save that console as an msc file and then re-access device manager as admin anytime you open that saved console file.

Answer (score 0):

The section below is a script snippet to run this script elevated

```
param([switch]$Elevated)

function Test-Admin {
    $currentUser = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
    $currentUser.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)
}

if ((Test-Admin) -eq $false)  {
    if ($elevated) {
        # tried to elevate, did not work, aborting
    } else {
        Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList ('-noprofile -noexit -file "{0}" -elevated' -f ($myinvocation.MyCommand.Definition))
    }
    exit
}

start "C:\Windows\System32\devmgmt.msc"
```